# ¿Como habilitar un input text y un select que estan deshabilitados y contenidos en un tr?

Tags: html, vue.js

estos input text y estos select se repiten por cada fila dependiendo del numero de registros y se habilitan al presionar un boton para poder editar sus contenidos hasta ahora solo he logrado que al presionar el boton correspondiente de editar de una fila se habiliten todos los campos de todas las filas y no es lo que quiero. aqui parte del codigo

```js
new Vue({
   el: '#main',
   data: {
    pregunta: {
     factor: '',
     item: ''
    },
    preguntas: [],
    factores: [],
    habilitaPregunta: true
   },
   created() {
    var currentUrl = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var id = currentUrl[3];

    this.getPreguntas(id);
    this.getFactores();
   },
   methods: {
    getPreguntas(id) {
     axios.get('/coord_ev/instrum/' + id)
      .then(res => {
       this.preguntas = res.data;
       console.log(this.preguntas);
      }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err)
      })
    },
    getFactores() {
     axios.get('/coord_ev/getFactores')
      .then(res => {
       this.factores = res.data;
       console.log(this.factores);
      })
    },
    habilitarPregunta(id) {
     this.habilitaPregunta = false;
    }
   }
  });
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-sm table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col" style="width: 5%">#</th>
   <th scope="col" style="width: 55%">Item</th>
    <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">Factor</th>
   <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">Acción</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr v-for="pregunta of preguntas">
   <th scope="row">1</th>
   <td>
     <input type="text" v-model="pregunta.nombre" class="form control" v-bind:disabled="habilitaPregunta"> 
   </td>
   <td>
    <select v-model="pregunta.factorId" class="form-control" v-bind:disabled="habilitaPregunta">
      <option v-for="opti in factores" v-bind:value="opti.id">
       {{ opti.nombre }}
     </option>
    </select>
   </td>
   <td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" v-if="habilitado" v-on:click="habilitarPregunta(pregunta.id)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una manera fácil de solucionar es almacenar el `id` de la pregunta seleccionada en lugar de un booleano; así nos aseguramos que la edición solo afecte a esa pregunta en cuestión.

Para las condiciones de edición en los controles, bastaría con:

```
v-if="preguntaSeleccionada !== pregunta.id"
```

Así mismo, puedes mostrar un botón "Guardar" para terminar la edición:

```
<a
  href="javascript:void(0)"
  v-if="preguntaSeleccionada === pregunta.id" v-on:click="guardarEdicion"
  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
>
  Save
</a>
```

**Ejemplo funcional**

> **Nota**: he añadido un par de estilos para que se esconda la apariencia del input y del select cuando no están siendo editados.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  data: {
    pregunta: {
      factor: '',
      item: ''
    },
    preguntas: [],
    factores: [],
    preguntaSeleccionada: null
    // habilitaPregunta: true
  },
  created() {
    /* var currentUrl = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var id = currentUrl[3];

    this.getPreguntas(id);
    this.getFactores(); */
    
    /* Para inicializar las preguntas y factores */
    this.preguntas = [{
      id: 1,
      nombre: '¿Cuántas bajas ocurrieron en la batalla de Stalingrado?',
      factorId: 2
    }, {
      id: 2,
      nombre: '¿Símbolo químico del cloro?',
      factorId: 3
    }]
    this.factores = [{
        id: 1,
        nombre: 'Geografía'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        nombre: 'Historia'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        nombre: 'Ciencia'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getPreguntas(id) {
      axios.get('/coord_ev/instrum/' + id)
        .then(res => {
          this.preguntas = res.data;
          console.log(this.preguntas);
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
    getFactores() {
      axios.get('/coord_ev/getFactores')
        .then(res => {
          this.factores = res.data;
          console.log(this.factores);
        })
    },
    edicionPregunta(id) {
      this.preguntaSeleccionada = id
      // this.habilitaPregunta = false;
    },
    guardarEdicion() {
      this.preguntaSeleccionada = null
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input, select {
  width: 100%;
}
input:disabled,
select:disabled {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-color: transparent;
}

select:disabled {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 5%">#</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 55%">Item</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">Factor</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">Acción</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(pregunta, index) of preguntas">
        <th scope="row">{{ index + 1 }}</th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" v-model="pregunta.nombre" class="form-control" v-bind:disabled="pregunta.id !== preguntaSeleccionada">
        </td>
        <td>
          <select v-model="pregunta.factorId" class="form-control" v-bind:disabled="pregunta.id !== preguntaSeleccionada">
            <option v-for="opti in factores" v-bind:value="opti.id">
              {{ opti.nombre }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" v-if="preguntaSeleccionada === null" v-on:click="edicionPregunta(pregunta.id)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" v-if="preguntaSeleccionada === pregunta.id" v-on:click="guardarEdicion" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta amigo, me sirvió de mucho, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Yo intentaria agregarle una propiedad a cada elemento de la lista, ya sea en el server o en el cliente, la cual puedas manipular con vue y dependiendo de esta habilitar o deshabilitar los controles.

Como en el siguiente ejemplo en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khjw8yLs/), yo le agregué la propiedad "disabled".

Este es el código *(en caso de que expire el jsfiddle) anterior*:

> NOTA: Aquí verás algunos mensajes en la consola, pero no son 
>   errores.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  data: {
    pregunta: {
      factor: '',
      item: ''
    },
    preguntas: [{
        factorId: 1,
        nombre: '',
        disabled: true,
      },
      {
        factorId: 1,
        nombre: '',
        disabled: true,
      }
    ],
    factores: [{
      id: 1,
      nombre: "Uno"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "Dos"
    }]
  },
  /*created() {
   var currentUrl = window.location.pathname.split('/');
   var id = currentUrl[3];

   this.getPreguntas(id);
   this.getFactores();
  },*/
  methods: {
    getPreguntas(id) {
      axios.get('/coord_ev/instrum/' + id)
        .then(res => {
          this.preguntas = res.data;
          console.log(this.preguntas);
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
    getFactores() {
      axios.get('/coord_ev/getFactores')
        .then(res => {
          this.factores = res.data;
          console.log(this.factores);
        })
    },
    habilitarPregunta(id) {
      this.habilitaPregunta = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="main">
  <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 5%">#</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 55%">Item</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">Factor</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">Acción</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="pregunta of preguntas">
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" v-model="pregunta.nombre" class="form control" v-bind:disabled="pregunta.disabled">
        </td>
        <td>
          <select v-model="pregunta.factorId" class="form-control" v-bind:disabled="pregunta.disabled">
            <option v-for="opti in factores" v-bind:value="opti.id">
              {{ opti.nombre }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" v-if="pregunta.disabled" v-on:click="pregunta.disabled = false" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muy bien que dejes el enlace del codigo, pero con el tiempo el enlace puede romperse y perderse. Te aconsejo que tambien coloques el codigo en tu respuesta, si en tal caso el enlace se rompe los demas usuarios todavia pueden seguir viendo el codigo.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa código del jsfiddle agregado a la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias a ambos!

Answer (score 1):

Cada registro debe tener un código único para agrupar los campos, por ejemplo el código de la pregunta. Ese código debe servir para identificar (poner ID en cada elemento) cada uno de de los elementos por fila y así poder bloquearlos/desbloquearlos. A continuación presento ejemplo ilustrativo:

Suponiendo que se tiene una sentencia "FOR" dentro de una tabla se procede a listar las filas:

```
<tr>     
    <td><input type="text" id="input1_{codigoUnico}" value="valor_y"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="input2_{codigoUnico}" value="valor_y"/></td>
    <td><button type='button'  onclick="unlockRow({codigoUnico});">Desbloquear</button></td>
</tr>
```

**En donde:**

**{codigoUnico}**: Corresponde a un valor único para cada registro.

**unlockRow**: Corresponde a una función que recibe dicho código único y lo usa para buscar a cada elemento y realizar alguna acción (bloquear/desbloquear).

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, la función para desbloquear cuando se haga clic en cada botón seria algo así (En este ejemplo se usa Jquery para manipular el DOM):

```
function unlockRow (codigoUnico){
  $("#input1_"+codigoUnico).attr("disabled",false);
  $("#input2_"+codigoUnico).attr("disabled",false);
}
```

Comment: Si bien es una respuesta válida, hay que intentar, en lo posible, de dar soluciones con el stack que usa el OP. En este caso, Vue.js. Saludos y bienvenido :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, es cierto. Estoy aprendiendo ;)